# Does 10.0.2.2 work on physical device?

Tags: android, timeout, xmpp, adb, asmack

I can't connect to my local xmpp server while debugging from my LG L9 phone (Android 4.1.2) connected via USB. I'm connecting to 10.0.2.2:5222, but still getting timeout exception. Can this loopback address be used on physical device too or is it available just for emulator?

Comment: Since when is `10.0.2.2` a loopback address?

Comment: see the table http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking

Comment: Ahh, ok, but it's an alias to the host loopback address, not a loopback address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, i tried to connect with 10.0.2.2:5222 from emulator to Openfire (xmpp server) running on my laptop (localhost) and it WORKS!

So yes, 10.0.2.2 only works with android emulator, not physical device connected via usb. If somebody wants to use physical device, he needs to create LAN (where xmpp server is connected) and connect traditionally with WiFi (so USB cable do not provide network connection between phone and computer, to which the phone is connected).

Comment: Hi, im trying to send events to an endpoint from a physical device to my local machine (localhost), was using 10.0.2.2 on an emulator..would you be able to provide any more details on how you went about this please, thanks

Comment: @Richlewis what do you mean? I just started emulator from eclipse, and then app running inside emulator connected to server running on same computer